# Duplicate files copied in APK junit/runner/smalllogo.gif

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso

i`m using Android-Studio 2.2.2 and did my first try using espresso for testing. With the attached build.gradle i got these error-message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task      ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK junit/runner/smalllogo.gif
File1: /home/christian/AndroidStudioProjects/PinMoney/app/libs/junit-4.12.jar
File2: /home/christian/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar
```

Here is the app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.1.0'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.cokuss.chhe.pinmoney"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENCE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
}
```

I have found several "Duplicate files copied" problems while searching but always with different files. Just adding

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENCE.txt'
        exclude 'smalllogo.gif' //added
}
```

does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENCE.txt'
        exclude 'smalllogo.gif' //added
}
```

was not the right solution, but with a little help from the Internet i found out that i had to make it more exact. Also i found out that smalllogo.gif was not the only thing i had to exclude. Here is the important part i had to change:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENCE.txt' // from old code 
    exclude 'junit/runner/smalllogo.gif'
    exclude 'junit/runner/logo.gif'
    exclude 'LICENSE-junit.txt'
}
```

I don`t think that this is the best way to fix this problem, but it works.